# R markdown 1.8.2 is not generating tabbed sections

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to update an R markdown document that uses the [`{.tabset}` option](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#tabbed_sections), but tabs do not get created as expected. Tabs generated fine the last time the report was generated (about six weeks ago). Both rmarkdown and pandoc have been updated since then, although I do not remember the exact versions that were used previously. Running under macOS Sierra 10.12.6, using R version 3.4.2, rmarkdown 1.8.2 and pandoc 2.0.2, the following does not create tabs:

````
---
title: "Missing Tabs"
output: html_document
---

# Tabset here {.tabset}
## tab1
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## tab 2
```{r}
summary(pressure)
```
````

Other options (e.g., table of contents, appearance, styling) seem to be functioning correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Add a space after the `tabset` line.  You need the extra space for the markdown to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Unfortunately, adding space (either after tablet, or around the subheadings) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error - I had no problem creating the the `tabset` after putting space between the `#` and `##` lines using the code provided.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Are you using the same versions of rmarkdown and pandoc?

Comment: In case it is helpful to anyone else, this was an issue with Pandoc 2.0. The most recent version of rmarkdown fixes this [incompatibility](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-markdown-1-8-2-is-not-generating-tabbed-sections/3019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/7663afa87bfc93590fa84bf587375bee9dfa4efd) in the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) of **rmarkdown**, which you can install via:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```